# Java Servlet insert to database without getParameter();

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I am trying to write servlet that inserts data to database(mysql). Problem is i need to write it in other class that is calling from servlet, and insert data without getParameter();
    UPD: here is a full code that i want compress into 2 classes, 1 for servlet, 1 for class that contains arguments

1. UserController.java

   ```
    protected void doPost(UserDao request, HttpServletResponse 
       response) throws ServletException, IOException {



       UserDao.addUser();

   }
   ```
2. UserDAO.java

   ```
    public class UserDao {

     private static Connection connection;

     public UserDao() {
     connection = (Connection) DBconnect.getConnection();
        }

    public static void addUser(String fname, String lname, String dob,      String email, String uid) {
        try {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = ((java.sql.Connection)      connection).prepareStatement("insert into users(firstname,lastname,dob,email) values (?, ?, ?, ? );");
     preparedStatement.setString(1, fname);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, lname);
    preparedStatement.setString(3, dob);
    preparedStatement.setString(4, email);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
     }


   }
   ```

Comment: Pass those values to the other class as arguments.

Comment: show us all the code involved.

Comment: @BackSlash ok, i will try to do it*

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte done!

Comment: @Nurik check out my answer, let me know if that helps. Not sure exactly what you wanted to do, so did it two different ways for you.

Answer (score 1):

From your code I can see all the parameters from request are now set in User object.

-> Write a DAO layer class that takes in a User object. Then write queries to insert data with user object.

Comment: i am not sure i understand what you have said. let me show you full code*

Comment: i have edited my code

Comment: The code looks working. Whats the error you are facing now to insert data into db?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking so i did it two different ways... 
Hopefully this will give you a good enough example to do whatever it is you wanted to do.

**----WITH USER OBJECT----**

**servlet:**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {

String fname = request.getParameter("firstName");
String lname = request.getParameter("lastName");
String dob = request.getParameter("dob");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
String uid = request.getParameter("userid");

dao.newUser(fname,lname,dob,email,uid);

}
```

**userDao**

```
 public class UserDao {

 private Connection connection;

 public UserDao() {
 connection = DbConnect.getConnection();
    }

public void newUser(String fname, String lname, String dob, String email, String uid){

    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstName(fname);
    user.setLastName(lname);
    user.setDob(dob);
    user.setEmail(email);

    addUser(user);}

}

    public void addUser(User user) {
        try {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
            .prepareStatement("insert into     
  users(firstname,lastname,dob,email) values (?, ?, ?, ? )");

    preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getFirstName());
    preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getLastName());
    preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getDob());
    preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getEmail());
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
     }


}
```

**----WITHOUT USER OBJECT----**

**servlet:**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {

String fname = request.getParameter("firstName");
String lname = request.getParameter("lastName");
String dob = request.getParameter("dob");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
String uid = request.getParameter("userid");

dao.addUser(fname,lname,dob,email,uid);

}
```

**userDao**

```
public class UserDao {

 private Connection connection;

 public UserDao() {
 connection = DbConnect.getConnection();
    }

public void addUser(String fname, String lname, String dob, String email, String uid) {
    try {
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection
        .prepareStatement("insert into users(firstname,lastname,dob,email) values (?, ?, ?, ? );");

preparedStatement.setString(1, fname);
preparedStatement.setString(2, lname);
preparedStatement.setString(3, dob);
preparedStatement.setString(4, email);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

} catch (SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
 }


}
```

Comment: i appreciate that. but it's not i wanted. i will try to rephrase what i want to do:

Comment: 1. use no getParamater() at all; for example if i dont know what type of data i want to insert in database (string, int, date etc.) 2. call class that already has inserting values from servlet

Comment: If you're submitting data from a form through http... you have to use getParameter(). By default those values are String values, but you can convert them to whatever you need.

Comment: public Servletik() {
        super();
      
    }

 
    protected void doPost(UserDao request, HttpServletResponse 
      response) throws ServletException, IOException {

      

      UserDao.addUser();

     }


 
}